# Trigger on affected column

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

i would like to have maximum count of inserted values to the table and have created trigger.

```
create trigger LimitTable
on [dbfastsprocess].[dbo].[fp_campaign_winner_list]
after insert
as
declare @tableCount int
select @tableCount = Count(*)
from [dbfastsprocess].[dbo].[fp_campaign_winner_list]
WHERE campaign_id = 13

if @tableCount > 1000
begin
    rollback
end
go
```

and i tried to insert values when campaign_id = 12,but the trigger also got triggered. How i wanted the trigger would triggered when only 'campaign_id = 13' 
is inserted?

Comment: If that trigger works at all, I'm pretty sure you are using SQL Server and not MySQL.  I changed the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is rather tricky in SQL Server, because you have to deal with multiple rows being inserted at the same time.

I think this does what you want:

```
create trigger LimitTable on dbfastsprocess.dbo.fp_campaign_winner_list
after insert as
begin

    declare @tableCount int;
    select @tableCount = Count(*)
    from dbfastsprocess.dbo.fp_campaign_winner_list wl
    where wl.campaign_id = 13;

    if (@tableCount > 1000 and
        exists (select 1 from inserted i where i.campaign_id = 13)
       )
    begin
        rollback
    end;
end;
go
```